# Admin account to access multiple gmail users in a domain

Tags: gmail, imap, gmail-imap

The question is specific to gmail business/ educational accounts. In order to read emails from a gmail account i have written a dll in c++ which executes IMAP commands and then parses their responses. With the current IMAP implementation i need to login to each users mailbox with his username and password information. So i was wondering if there is any option in gmail business with which i can login to multiple users in a domain with single admin users credentials and without to need to get password from each indivdual user in the domain?

Comment: This is not a programming question. Ask gmail-for-business support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a Service Account in the Google Developers Console and give it access to the Email scope for the domain. Whenever you want to access a mailbox, you'd obtain an access token (which can be cached for up to an hour) and then use it with the XOAUTH2 SASL for authentication.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/xoauth2_protocol